# If $|G|=2^2\cdot 5 \cdot 19\Rightarrow n_5=n_{19}=1$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, semidirect-product

By using the Sylow Theorems we need $n_5\in \{1,2^2\cdot 19\}$ and $n_{19}\in\{1,20\}$.

**First Case:** If $n_5=2^2\cdot 19$ and $n_{19}=20$, the group cannot stand the pressure: we have too many elements. Indeed, because $5$ and $19$ are prime, the Sylow groups intercept trivially and there are $2^2\cdot 19\cdot 4$ elements of order $5$ and $20\cdot 18$ elements of order $19$. But this yields a contradiction:  $|G|=2^2\cdot 5 \cdot 19<2^2\cdot 19\cdot 4+20\cdot 18$.

**Second Case:** Say $n_5=1$ and $n_{19}=20$. Take $P\in \text{Syl}_5 G$ and $Q\in \text{Syl}_{19}G$. We have $Q\cap P=1$ and $P\unlhd G$ therefore $P\rtimes Q\leq G$. I wanted to prove normality **(haven't been able to prove it thus far)** $P\rtimes Q \unlhd G$. Because if it were normal, we would have:

$$gQg^{-1}\leq gP\rtimes Q g^{-1}=P\rtimes Q$$

Thus all Sylow-19 groups would be there and we would need $20\cdot 18$ elements of order $19$ there. But the size of $P\rtimes Q$ is only $ 19\cdot 5$. Absurd.

**Third Case:** I think we reach a similar contradiction by assuming $n_5=2^2\cdot 19$ and $n_{19}=1$. Indeed, we would have $Q\rtimes P\leq G$. And if we assume normality, all Sylow $5$ subgroups would be in the semidirect product. Thus we would have $2^2\cdot 19\cdot 4$ elements of order $5$ in a group of order $19\cdot 5$.

> Basically I need to prove the semidirect product is normal in the second and third cases.

Comment: If we only had one factor of $2$ the semidirect products would be immediately normal, because of $[G: Q\rtimes P]=2$. The $2^2$ term makes it harder...

Comment: If $n_5=1$, then a Sylow-5, call it $P$ is normalized by elements of order $19$. But the automorphism group of $C_5$ is cyclic of order four, so conjugation by an element of order $19$ on $P$ must be the trivial automorphism. In other words, in this all $Q$s must *centralize* $P$, and therefore $P$ also centralizes $Q$ which implies $n_{19}=1$.

Comment: Similarly, the automorphism group of $C_{19}$ is cyclic of order $18$, so if Q$ is normalized by $P$ it is again centralized by it. You fill the rest.

Comment: As the order of $g$ is $19$, the order of $\phi_g$ must be a factor of $19$. After all, $(\phi_g)^k=\phi_{g^k}$.

Comment: Or, more generally $\phi_x\circ\phi_y=\phi_{xy}$. In other words,  conjugation defines *an action* of the bigger group on a normal subgroup. This argument is all over the place - can't do without it. Learn it!

Comment: Ow. So the restriction has a certain order dividing $4$ and $19$. That is why it needs to be trivial. I now see $g pg^{-1}=p$ for all $p\in P$ and for all $g\in Q$ because all of those have order $19$ or are the identity. How did you continue?

Comment: Do consider a detailed argument as an answer. That way you may get more feedback (and we get this question out of the unanswered pile). Self-answering is ok, even when propelled by hints.

Comment: $G$ acts on the Sylow-5 and Sylow-19 subgroups transitively. Given that a Sylow-5 and a Sylow-19 are mutually central, it follows that $n_5 \le 4$ and $n_{19} \le 4$.

Comment: @SeanEberhard Unbelievable. Lol. I must be incredibly slow. $G*Q=\text{Syl}_qG$. And $P*Q=\{Q\}$ because conjugation in $P$ does nothing to $Q$. How does your inequality follow?

Comment: The number of Sylow-$p$ subgroups is $[G:N_G(P)]$, and $N_G(P)$ contains $P \times Q$, so $[G:N_G(P)] \le [G:P\times Q] = 4$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jyrki Lahtonen and Sean Eberhard have solved this in two lines in the comment section, but encouraged me to write a more detailed answer.

We already know $n_5=1$ or $n_{19}=1$. Suppouse by ways of contradiction that $n_{19}=1$ and $n_5=2^2\cdot 19$, we have that $\exists ! P\in \text{Syl}_{19}G$, so $P\lhd G$. Let us take $Q\in \text{Syl}_{5}G$ and consider the semidirect product $P\rtimes Q$.

The semidirect product has four lateral classes $[G: P\rtimes Q]=|G|/|P\rtimes Q|=4$. Take $U \in \text{Syl}_2 G$ we know $U=\{g_0,g_1,g_2,g_3\}$. If $g_iP\rtimes Q=g_jP\rtimes Q$ we have $g_j^{-1}g_i\in P\rtimes Q \Rightarrow g_j^{-1}g_i=1$ because $g_j^{-1}g_j \in (P\rtimes Q)\cap U$ and therefore it has order dividing $4$ and also $19\cdot 5$. Therefore $g_j P\rtimes Q$ are all lateral classes and $U (P\rtimes Q)=G$ where we consider the usual set multiplication. Indeed :$$G=\dot{\cup}_{i=0}^3 g_i Q\rtimes P=U(P\rtimes Q)$$

Let $g\in Q$, clearly $\phi_g|_P(x)=gxg^{-1}$ is an automorphism $\phi_g|_P:P\rightarrow P$ (because $P\lhd G$ )such that $|\phi_g|$ divides 5 (because $\phi_g^5(x)=g^5xg^{-5}=x=I(x)$).

We know $P\approx \mathbb{Z}_{19}$. This means an automorphism $\psi$ is well defined if we know to what generator $1$ is taken. In other words we are interested in knowing $\psi_j(1)=j$ such that $0<j<19$. Also:

$$\psi_j\psi_k(1)=\psi_j (k)=k\psi_j(1)=kj=\psi_{jk }$$

So automorphisms are actually $\mathbb{Z}_{19}^*$ in disguise. But that is a group of order $18$. So $\phi_g|_P$ has an order dividing $18$ and $5$ and hence it must be trivial. In other words, $gxg^{-1}=x$ for $\forall x\in P$ and $\forall g\in Q$. We will actually need this in the form $g=xgx^{-1}$ $\forall x\in P$ and $\forall g\in Q$.

Let us compute conjugacy classes for $Q$ by taking an arbitray $g\in G=U(P\rtimes Q)$:

$$gQg^{-1}=upqQq^{-1}p^{-1}u^{-1}=uQu^{-1}$$

All conjugacy classes are determined by this $u$ term. But there are only four possibilities for it $(|U|=4)$. This means $n_5\leq 4$. Contradiction.